# display all data labels on highchart piechart

Tags: reactjs, charts, highcharts, pie-chart, react-highcharts

I have a highchart pie chart but it does not display all the data labels. it only displays the dataLabels of the larger slices. i want the chart to display all the data labels even the ones for the smaller slices.
is there a way to format the chart to see all the data labels? can anyone please help with this?
[example code](https://codepen.io/jjpo/pen/BaMKRqd)

````
function generatePieData(numPieces) {
    let data = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= numPieces; i++) {
        let piece = {
            y: i
        };
        data.push(piece);
    }
    return data;
}

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    series: [{
         dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
            },
        borderWidth: 0,
        borderRadius: 0,
        data: generatePieData(100)
    }]
});```
````

Answer (score 0):

When there is insufficient space, Highcharts will selectively display data labels to ensure the chart remains legible. By default, each data label includes padding, and if it overlaps with another label, it gets concealed. To display all data labels, you must adjust the padding to 0.

So in your code add padding: 0 in dataLabels like this:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'pie'
},
title: {
    text: ''
},
series: [{
     dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
            padding: 0
        },
    borderWidth: 0,
    borderRadius: 0,
    data: generatePieData(100)
}]
})
```

hope this helps !

Comment: hi this displayed more data labels but still not all:

Comment: it's impossible to, as there's not much space if you tested your code, the portions are too small and it would ruin the ui. I would recommemnd maybe using a differnet library. but still you'd have to really personalies the labels components so it would display data even if the Chart if too divided. You can also maybe think about using a different Chart other than the pie.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading the related GitHub thread:
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/7907

You might explore one of the solutions provided in the thread. Additionally, you can experiment with various options such as `dataLabels.distance`, `pie.center`, `pie.size`, and the font size of dataLabels.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'pie',
    height: 900,
    width: 900,
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  series: [{
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      distance: 130,
      formatter() {
        const fontSize =
          this.percentage < 0.4 ? 5 :
          this.percentage < 0.7 ? 6 :
          this.percentage < 1 ? 7 : 8;
        return `<span style="font-size: ${fontSize}px"><b>${this.key}</b>: ${this.percentage.toFixed(2)} %</span>`;
      },
      connectorPadding: 0,
      padding: 0
    },
    center: ["50%", "30%"],
    size: '30%',
    borderWidth: 0,
    borderRadius: 0,
    data: generatePieData(100)
  }]
})
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9arpx4bt/